# How to add css to specific php echos

Tags: php, css, html, echo

Hello i want to add specific styling to each of these echos but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone please help? I tried adding specific div to them did not work either.

```
echo "<table>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {       

        echo '<tr><td style="height=100px"><a href="">
       <img src="'.$row['Image'].'" width="200px" height="200px" /></a></td>';


            echo'<td>' .$row['ShopName'].'</td></tr>';

            echo'<td>' .$row['ADDRESS'].'</td></tr>';

            echo'<td>' .$row['Region'].'</td></tr>';

            echo'<td>' .$row['DiscountRate'].'</td></tr>';

            echo'<td>' .$row['Conditions'].'</td></tr>';




    echo "</table>";


        }else{
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $con->close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `style="height:100px;"` not `style="height=100px"`